# Mostrar campos de una base de datos en una vista diferente a la del controlador a la que esta asociada

Tags: laravel, vistas

En mi controlador ProfesoresController tengo esto

```
    $datos['profesores']=Profesores::paginate(3);
    return view('profesores.index',$datos);
```

y puedo recuperar los datos en la vista index.blade.php de la siguiente forma

```
 @foreach($profesores as $profesor)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
            <td>
            <img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="{{ asset('storage').'/'. $profesor->Foto }}" alt="" width="70px">
            </td>
            <td>{{ $profesor->Nombre }}</td>
            <td>{{ $profesor->Descripcion }}</td>
            <td>
            <a href="{{ url('/profesores/'.$profesor->id.'/edit')}}" class="btn btn-warning">Editar </a> 
            <form method="post" action="{{ url('/profesores/'.$profesor->id) }}"  style="display:inline" >
            {{csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('DELETE')}}
            <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Borrar?');" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
            </form>
            </td>

        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Ahora mi pregunta es la siguiennte, Como llamar los mismos datos desde otra vista por ejemplo para mostrar la informacion en el index o pagina inicial de la web

Comment: Los datos en dos vistas a la vez o solo mostrarlos en una distinta a la actual ?

Answer (score 0):

Igual. Nada te impide utilizar un modelo fuera de "su controlador". Lo puedes llamar desde el controlador de la página principal (o una ruta en `routes/web.php`), por ejemplo `/home`:

```php
$datos['profesores']=Profesores::paginate(3);
return view('home',$datos);
```

Y en `home.blade.php`:

```php
@foreach($profesores as $profesor)
    ...
@endforeach
```